# Powershell: to merge 2 similar user ouputs from Exchange and AD

Tags: powershell

Hi I have pulled some data out from exchange ($results) and AD ($results2)

```
$results | Select distinguishedName,Name,Email,SamAccountName,CompanyName,Enabled,have_exhange

$results2 | select distinguishedName,Name,EmailAddress,SamAccountName,Company,Enabled,Have_citrix
```

As you can see they are identical except for the last value.

Many users will be in both `$results` and `$results2` but some will be on only one of them.

I have been trying to figure out how to merge these two variables so a user only appears on one line when i export it to csv.

If a user exist in both they should have both of the last columns (have_exhange and have_citrix)

Some pointers on how to solve this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following

```
$results, $results2 | Group-Object -property 'SamAccountName'
```

Then, you will have an array of objects with Count,Name and group.